# Which topological spaces does every ultrafilter on the clopens converge?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

Compact spaces are exactly those in which every ultrafilter on $\mathcal{P}X$ converges, or equivalently ultrafilters on the frame of opens $\mathcal{O}X$. In Stone spaces, or more generally compact $0$-dimensional spaces, since there is a basis of clopens, any ultrafilter on $\mathcal{B}X$ the boolean algebra of clopens will also converge.

But it seems that every ultrafilter on $\mathcal{B}X$ converging does not imply $0-$dimensionality, as the Sierpinski space has boolean algebra $2$, and its only ultrafilter is the set {$S$}, but this does converge to $0$, but the Sierpinski space does not have a basis of clopens.

Therefore I am interested to know if there is a characterisation of for which spaces all ultrafilters on the boolean algebras of clopens will converge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the **$H(i)$-spaces** studied in

> C. Scarborough, A. Stone, [*Products of Nearly Compact Spaces*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1966-124-01/S0002-9947-1966-0203679-7/S0002-9947-1966-0203679-7.pdf), Trans. Amer. Math. Soc., **124** (1966), 131-147.

A Hausdorff space $X$ has the property that each of its open ultrafilters converges if and only if $X$ is H-closed (i.e. a closed subspace of every other Hausdorff space in which it embeds). A regular Hausdorff space has this property if and only if it is compact.

Nevertheless, the $H(i)$-property studied by Scarborough and Stone was introduced purposefully to avoid separation assumptions. It is remarked in the paper that;

> A space $X$ is an $H(i)$-space if and only if every open cover of $X$ has a finite subfamily whose union is a dense subspace of $X$.

There are also other classes of spaces considered in the paper. Namely the $H(ii)$-space, the $R(i)$-spaces, and the $R(ii)$-spaces.

Comment: Do you know, out of interest, why these are called $H(i)$-spaces, when there's no dependency on a variable $i$?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. I'm guessing the H comes from the connection between these spaces and the Hausdorff H-closed spaces. As for the $i$ and $ii$, perhaps there was once a longer list of properties that the authors considered that either had already appeared in the literature under different names, or were judged to be uninteresting before the final version of the paper was published.